# Pointer to an array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm currently trying to write a program for a student database assignment. After manually setting 3 elements of the structure array, the next 3 students' details are inputted by the user.

I am trying to write a function that finds the oldest age of the 6 students and returns it as a student_t entry at index max. I'm struggling with how to actually give the function the pointer that is pointing to the first element of the array stdt[6] and then using the pointer within the function. I also have no idea how I would go about returning to main the entry that has the highest age. If I'm trying to say that the value of an element of array of structures is equal to some other integer (max), doesn't that mean that max is now some other block of memory with an integer value and not linked to the array? So I'm not sure how I would return the entry that has the highest age after the function determines the max age.

This is all I've written so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
char *name;
char *surname;
char *UUN;
char *department;
char gender;
int age;
}student_t;

student_t findOldest(student_t *studentarr, int len){
  int i;
  int x;
  int max;
  max=0;
 for(i=0;i<len;i++){
   (p+i).age=x;
   if(x>max){
   x=max;
   }
    }
}

int main() {
int i;
 student_t stdt[6]={{"John","Bishop","s1234","Inf",'m',18},{"Lady","Cook","s2345","Eng",'f',21},{"James","Jackson","s33456","Eng",'m',17}};
 student_t *p=&stdt[0];

for(i=3;i<6;i++) {
printf("First name: \n");
scanf("%s",stdt[i].name);
printf("Last name: \n");
scanf("%s",stdt[i].surname);
printf("UUN: \n");
scanf("%s",stdt[i].UUN);
printf("Department: \n");
scanf("%s",stdt[i].department);
printf("Gender (m/f): \n");
scanf("%c",stdt[i].gender);
printf("Age: \n");
scanf("%d",stdt[i].age);
}
 findOldest(p,6);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) `scanf("%s",stdt[i].name);` : Area in which to store the string has not been prepared.

Comment: I thought by initialising the array to have 6 elements while only setting 3 meant that there would still be 3 blocks of memory available for the next 3 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
student_t findOldest(student_t *p, int len){
 int i;
 student_t max = *(p+0);

 for(i=1;i<len;i++)
    {if((*(p+i)).age > max.age)
     max = *(p+i);
    }
 return max;
}
```

You want to return the student so keep the student in your max variable not the age. And to refer to pointers either use

(p+i)->age > max.age

or use

(*(p+i)).age > max.age

But there are other problems with the code.

Comment: Thank you. If I had to keep the "findOldest(student_t *studentarr..." part, would I just replace studentarr wherever p is in the function?

Comment: exactly.  Replace each place of p with studentarr.

Comment: What other problems are there that I should look in to? At the moment it seems to fit the specifications required.

Comment: The function I helped you with is fine.  However, the loop for user input with the printf, scanf does not run for me - I get a segmentation fault error.  If it compiles for you then maybe you are using a different compiler.